# Overriding the DNS for a domain is not working

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, localhost

My clients' website is live at this moment, and I am migrating the website to my new Web Hosting Server. I already uploaded the site to the new server.

Before changing the DNS, I am testing the site by modifying my hosts' file (windows local machine) to override the DNS for the domain.

```
123.123.123.123 www.thedomain.com
```

Then after that, I visited the URL. The old website is still showing, not the new one. Tried to ping it using Command Prompt and the IP address is the IP of the new server. But trying to ping it online shows the IP of the old server.

Why is that? Is there anything I could do to view the newly uploaded site?

*This is the result when I tried to run `curl -I www.thedomain.com` using the command prompt.
[image]

Comment: Quit and restart your browser.

Comment: Tried that but not working, I even restarted my Computer.

Comment: Does `curl -I www.thedomain.com` go to the right site? Does it perhaps redirect you to the old one?

Comment: @SebastianStark help, how could I do that?

Comment: Can you put `curl -I www.thedomain.com` in the command line (of course replace with your real domain), run it, and paste the output here?

Comment: @SebastianStark Tried what you've said, I updated my post for the result. But I don't know exactly the meaning of it.

Comment: The output should tell you if you're connected to the correct site. Only you can tell if that's the case. At least it shows that there's no redirect in place.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain "But trying to ping it online shows the IP of the old server."

Try to put thedomain.com also in in hosts file, plus any other 3d used in your project (e.g. images.thdomain.com)

addendum:

If you use some sort of proxy the connection is made from your proxy and modifying your local host file is not relevant

Comment: What I mean is looking the server ip of the domain online using https://asm.ca.com/en/ping.php, I already put the domain name in host file as I mentioned above.

Comment: This is not going to work: Writing stuff in your hosts (either Linux /etc/hosts or Windows \WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) works only locally on your system.

Comment: Well, I already did that on my local machine. I put the IP of the new server together with the domain name. But not working.

Comment: What is VideoCacheBox?